# Java AWT EventQueue "Not on FX application thread" exception in JavaFX

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, javafx, illegalstateexception

I've got a problem by migrating an application from Swing to JavaFX.

To make it as simple as I can, at the start of my application, a JavaFX `Stage` is initialized in the main JavaFX class (Main.java). At the end of initialization (in JFX thread), I open a Swing customed `JDialog` (not migrated at the moment) which asks the user to choose a device. In this `JDialog` I have an `ObservableModel` which send as parameters entries from user in the device selection `JDialog`. My main JavaFX class is an `Observer` and I get the entries from the selected device by overriding the `update()` function. **So far, all is working fine**.

And then, still in the `update()` function, if the user is not connected, i want to open a login dialog which I created in JavaFX (was a Swing `JDialog` before migration). And when I try to open it, I get an `java.lang.IllegalStateException` exception telling `"Not on FX application thread; currentThread = AWT-EventQueue-0"`

**Some code now :**

JavaFX `Main` class Main.java : Important is that I open the `JDialog` by calling `openSlpDlg()` which will ask the user to choose a device and the result of the selection will be returned in the `update()` method as argument

```
public class Main extends Application implements Observer {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        // init stage
        stage.setTitle(Messages.getString("Appli_HaslerST"));
        stage.getIcons().add(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("../gifs/application.gif")));
        mainContainer = new BorderPane();
        Scene root = new Scene(mainContainer, 1200, 1000);
        stage.setScene(root);

        // init stage content
        initialize();

        stage.show();

        // open that device selection dialog
        openSlpDlg();   

        this.stage = stage;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {

        // called when user has chosen a device in the JDialog

        if (arg instanceof Object[]) {
            Object[] set = (Object[]) arg;

            try {

                // con is an Interface that will create the correct
                // device JPanel, depending of selection.
                // the JPanel is created in constructor of MainGUI 


                // Start method of device application which creates a 
                // new MainGUI (JPanel)
                // AbstractTabbedPanel is a customed JPanel
                AbstractTabbedPanel panel = con.getTabbedPanel();

            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
    }


}
```

The external device application returns a `JPanel` which will be stored in my stage by using `SwingNode` (it works fine). But at the creation of this `JPanel`, in the `MainGUI` (as mentionned in the comments in the code above), I check if the user is logged, and if not, I open the login dialog which is a JavaFX `Dialog<R>`

---

`MainGUI` from external application. `con.getTabbedPane()` called by the JavaFX Main application in `update()` (in the code above) will create a new `MainGUI`.

```
public class MainGUI extends JPanel {

    public MainGUI() {

        // [...] all initalization done in constructor

        // test if user connected
        if (LocalAccessControl.getInstance().getAccessControl() == null) {

            // not connected case

            // JavaFX custom login extends from Dialog<LoginInfo>
            LoginDlg login;
            login = new LoginDlg()

            // show login dialog and get a LoginInfo object with
            // user info
            LoginInfo userInfo = login.showLogin();
        }
    }


}
```

And by `LoginInfo userInfo = login.showLogin();` I get this exception :`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = AWT-EventQueue-0`

Problem is, I need login info stored in `userInfo` to continue constructing my `JPanel` in the constructor (so in AWT EventQueue thread) but my LoginDlg is JavaFX implemented. I tried to use `Platform.runLater(new Runnable(){...})` but it doesn't work and it's normal, because I'm currently not using JavaFX thread and it's not executed immediately in FX thread (the dialog is never displayed and login can't be done, so the JPanel will be null and a warning message is displayed telling that connection was not possible).

I've already seen few posts on stackoverflow for this exception but I think my case is a bit more tricky and I can't find a great solution to get over this.

Hope you can help me. If you need more details, please ask!

Comment: 1. What does `openSlpDlg()` actually do? You are running that on the FX Application Thread, so if it, e.g. creates a Swing Dialog and displays it, you're violating Swing's threading rules (even though it's not giving an exception). 2. How does `login.showLogin()` work? Is it using a `showAndWait` on a FX dialog (or stage)? That's probably being executed on the AWT event dispatch thread (responding to an AWT event), so it needs to be on the FX Application Thread. Do you need to use the resulting `userInfo` back on the FX thread or the AWT thread?

Comment: @James_D
1. `openSlpDlg()` creates the JDialog with its content and shows it
2. `login.showLogin()` shows the JFX login `Dialog` by using `showAndWait()` and waits for a result (configured with the `setResultConverter()` method). The result is returned as a `LoginInfo` which contains the user info (password, username, ...) and yes, I need `userInfo` to create a label in the JPanel which shows the user connected (username)

Comment: @James_D I know I can't use JFX `Dialog.showAndWait()` if i'm not on the JFX thread, but I can't use `Platform.runLater()` to show the login because I absolutely need the login to be shown during the construction of the `JPanel` (too long to explain why). The MainGUI class will also be implemented in JavaFX in the future and will be a Pane instead of a swing JPanel (and so it will always run on the JFX thread, I think the problem will be solved). That's why i'm not looking for several changes, i just want to test my new JavaFX `LoginDlg`.

Comment: You simply have to manage the threading if you're going to use both toolkits together. `showAndWait()` is a blocking call. If you merely want to test `LoginDlg`, just write a separate test case (using all JavaFX) to test it.

Comment: Some updates to answer to show how you can block the `MainGUI` constructor until login is complete. This is not a good strategy though.

Answer (score 1):

Mixing Swing and JavaFX is tricky, because each toolkit is single-threaded and each has its own UI thread on which "live" UI elements must be managed. For Swing, see ["Swing's Threading Policy" in the javax.swing package documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/package-summary.html); for JavaFX see the ["Threading" section of the `Application` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html). JavaFX attempts, where possible, to enforce these rules by throwing a runtime exception if you violate them (as you have seen); Swing does not throw exceptions. In either case, violating the threading rules has the potential to leave your application in an indeterminate state and cause bugs at essentially arbitrary times in the application lifecycle.

You can use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> { ... });` to invoke code on the AWT event dispatch thread, and `Platform.runLater(() -> { ... });` to invoke code on the FX application thread. These calls are *asynchronous*, so they will not be executed immediately; in other words code immediately following these calls is likely to be executed before the code submitted to the UI threads.

Additionally, you should not make blocking calls on the UI threads, except where these blocking calls are explicitly designed to do so. For example, if `dialog` is a FX dialog (or stage), `dialog.showAndWait()` is a blocking call that is designed to be safely executed on the FX Application thread; however you should not make calls that block for input from an FX dialog on the AWT event dispatch thread.

You haven't shown a complete example in your code, but it looks like you need something like this:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {

    // init stage
    stage.setTitle(Messages.getString("Appli_HaslerST"));
    stage.getIcons().add(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("../gifs/application.gif")));
    mainContainer = new BorderPane();
    Scene root = new Scene(mainContainer, 1200, 1000);
    stage.setScene(root);

    // init stage content
    initialize();

    stage.show();

    // open that device selection dialog: this is a Swing dialog, 
    // so it must be performed on the AWT event dispatch thread:
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(this::openSlpDlg);   

    this.stage = stage;

}
```

Your `update()` method is executed as a response to user input in the AWT event dispatch thread (from an action listener in the Swing dialog shown from `openSlpDlg`, I am assuming); hence it, and the methods it invokes, such as `new MainGUI()` are executed on the AWT event dispatch thread. So you now need:

```
public MainGUI() {

    // this method is executed on the AWT event dispatch thread

    // [...] all initalization done in constructor

    // test if user connected
    if (LocalAccessControl.getInstance().getAccessControl() == null) {

        // not connected case

        // JavaFX custom login extends from Dialog<LoginInfo>

        // Tricky part. We need to create a JavaFX dialog (so must be 
        // done on the FX Application Thread), show it and wait for the result
        // (so make a blocking call, which needs to be on a background thread),
        // and process the result back on the AWT thread.

        // task to execute on the FX Application Thread, returning a LoginInfo:
        FutureTask<LoginInfo> getLoginTask = new FutureTask<>(() -> {
            LoginDlg login;
            login = new LoginDlg()

            // show login dialog and get a LoginInfo object with
            // user info
            return login.showLogin();
        });

        // execute the task on the FX Application Thread:
        Platform.runLater(getLoginTask);

        // now create a background thread that waits for the login task to complete, 
        // and processes the result back on the AWT event dispatch thread:
        Thread waitForLoginThread = new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                final LoginInfo userLogin = getLoginTask.get();
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {

                    // process userLogin here...

                });
            } catch (InterruptedException exc) {
                throw new Error("Unexpected interruption waiting for login");
            } catch (ExecutionException exc) {
                Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "Error getting login info", exc);
            }
        });
        waitForLoginThread.start();
    }
}
```

If you *really* want to block the `MainGUI` constructor until the FX dialog is dismissed, you could do it by waiting for the task submitted to the FX Application Thread to complete directly there (instead of in a background thread):

```
public MainGUI() {

    // this method is executed on the AWT event dispatch thread

    // [...] all initalization done in constructor

    // test if user connected
    if (LocalAccessControl.getInstance().getAccessControl() == null) {

        // not connected case

        // JavaFX custom login extends from Dialog<LoginInfo>

        // Tricky part. We need to create a JavaFX dialog (so must be 
        // done on the FX Application Thread), show it and wait for the result
        // (so make a blocking call, which needs to be on a background thread),
        // and process the result back on the AWT thread.

        // task to execute on the FX Application Thread, returning a LoginInfo:
        FutureTask<LoginInfo> getLoginTask = new FutureTask<>(() -> {
            LoginDlg login;
            login = new LoginDlg()

            // show login dialog and get a LoginInfo object with
            // user info
            return login.showLogin();
        });

        // execute the task on the FX Application Thread:
        Platform.runLater(getLoginTask);

        // wait for task submitted to FX Application Thread to complete.
        // note this blocks the AWT event dispatch thread:
        try {
            final LoginInfo userLogin = getLoginTask.get();

            // process userLogin here...

        } catch (InterruptedException exc) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        } catch (ExecutionException exc) {
            Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "Error getting login info", exc);
        }
    }
}
```

I don't recommend this approach: it will make the Swing UI unresponsive and may result in a poor user experience. It's generally better to structure the application so that either `MainGUI` can be shown without login having completed, and then updated when login is complete; or so that the `MainGUI` constructor is not invoked at all until login is complete.

Comment: Just need some quick fix before and I will try this. Thanks for help, seems to be a good solution.

Comment: so I did some huge changes in my code and I migrated the JDialog to choose a device to a JavaFX Dialog and have no more this problem. What should I do with this post?